# Erro PHP - "}" Aparece na página

Tags: php, html

Eu criei uma lista em PHP, só que por algum motivo o "}" aparece toda hora que um novo dado é adicionado na lista, o que eu posso fazer para retirar esse colchete? 

Obs: Quando eu tento retirar o "}" da linha 35 o PHP me retorna com esse erro

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Sistema_Aluno\con_aluno.php on line 35

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Con - Aluno</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>RM</th>
<th>Nome</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>TurmaID</th>
</tr>
<?php
include_once("conexao.php");
$select = 'Select * from aluno order by Nome DESC';
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,$select);
$lista = 0;
while($dado = mysqli_fetch_array ($sql))
{
$lista++;?>
}
<tr>
<td><?php echo $dado['RM'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $dado['Nome'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $dado['Email'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $dado['Turma_ID'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Retire `}` abaixo de `$lista++;>`

Correto:

```
$lista = 0;
while($dado = mysqli_fetch_array ($sql))
{
$lista++;?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $dado['RM'];?></td>
```

Comment: Funcionou! Eu cometi um erro extremamente bobo, obrigado pela ajuda!